# Job Schedular stops working when app gets killed

Tags: android

Job Schedular stops working when app gets killed, even if i enable the auto start option from setting.
In my redmi 5 phone.

Comment: also try the WorkManager but the result get same

Comment: Xiaomi has it's own custom Task manager. so please expect to encounter not a usual behaviour from your phone.

Comment: so what will we the solution for custom os devices?

Comment: You may have to use foreground service to keep it live all the time

Comment: In WorkManager did you used PeriodicWorkRequest? You may know the, Periodic work interval minimum time is 900000 seconds or in other words 15 minutes.

Comment: used OneTimeWorkRequest, just want to compress the large videos. any solution ?

Comment: If I do not know wrong, you should allow keep app running in the background from settings, you can get detail info from googling